# SOLVED: Multiplicity of the eigenvalues of the sum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

*** Question Solved ***

This question ultimately was about the conditions for violation of the Wigner-von Neumann non-crossing rule, which is still an open field of research.

Thank you very much to all those who contributed.

***Edit in response to the comments received*** (see below for initial, disproved, conjecture):

Let $\boldsymbol{D} \in \mathrm{Diag}_n\left(\mathbb{R}\right) $ be an invertible diagonal matrix that has different, unique real values on the diagonal.

Let $\boldsymbol{d} \in \mathrm{Diag}_m\left(\mathbb{R}\right) $ be a smaller diagonal matrix , with $m<n$. $\boldsymbol{d}$ is not necessarily invertible and could have repeated values on the diagonal.

Finally, let $\boldsymbol{M} \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n,m}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ be a rectangular matrix that is full and random enough that it is of rank $m$ (i.e. $\boldsymbol{M}$ would be invertible where it not for $m \neq n $ ).

The conjecture is that $\boldsymbol{D} + \boldsymbol{M} \boldsymbol{d} \boldsymbol{D}^\top $ has simple eigenvalues (i.e. no multiplicities higher than 1).

Thank you very much for any help towards demonstrating this result.

***Initial Statement*** (disproved by counter-example in comments):

If $\boldsymbol{A}$ only has simple eigenvalues, are there properties concerning the multiplicity of the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{B}$ ?

This question is much narrower than the general Additive Eigenvalue Problem conjectured by Horn (1962) and demonstrated in 1999 by Knutson and Tao. We do not ask *what are the eigenvalues* of $\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{B}$, but only *whether they are simple*.

Here is the statement:

Let $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ be two symmetric matrices (i.e. in $\mathcal{S}_n\left(\mathbb{R}\right) $). 
We suppose all eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A}$ are simple (i.e. multiplicity 1) and $\boldsymbol{A}$ is invertible. 
There are no restrictions on the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{B}$, in particular it is likely that $0$ is an eigenvalue of high multiplicity. 
$\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ do not commute.

I conjecture that the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{B}$ are all simple (i.e. $\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{B}$ has, as $\boldsymbol{A}$, only eigenvalues of multiplicity 1). However, a proof is still elusive. Can anyone help ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Certainly not true without further assumptions on $B$: take $B=-A$. It will work for small $B$.

Comment: @christianremling but your A and B do commute.

Comment: @ViditNanda: I (wrongly) read "do not commute" as "do not necessarily commute", but modify my $B$ on a suitable subspace if that bothers you.

Comment: Perhaps instead of  "$A$ and $B$ do not commute", a better condition would be that they have no common invariant subspaces.

Comment: What do you mean by $\boldsymbol{M} \boldsymbol{d} \boldsymbol{D}^\top $?  $Md$ is $n \times m$, $D$ is $n \times n$ (and symmetric, so no need to transpose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your conjecture is wrong, it still is quite unlikely that $A+B$ has a double eigenvalue. If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, the set of matrices $B$ such that $A+B$ has a double eigenvalue has codimension 2, not 1. So a crossing is "doubly more unlikely" than what one would expect.

A striking manifestation of this phenomenon is the so-called *avoidance of crossing*: take two random symmetric matrices $A,B$, and plot the eigenvalues of $A+tB$ as a function of $t$. Generically (i.e., "with probability 1"), this plot contains no crossings; and it often contains lines that draw very close, seem to meet and then suddenly diverge; for instance, see the plots in [this web page](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/fchamizo/oscuro/avoidance.html).

This phenomenon is discussed in more detail in Chapter 10 of Lax's *Linear algebra and its applications*.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very insightful comment. Indeed, I now believe the answer to this question is to be found through the Wigner-von Neumann non-crossing rule and the extensive literature surrounding it. In particular, the following article provides with some properties on the matrix $\boldsymbol{M}$ for crossing to happen: _The link between integrability, level crossings and
exact solution in quantum models_ , H.K. Owusu, K. Wagh and E. A. Yuzbashyan, in J. Phys. A: Math. Theor. 42 (2009) 035206 (24pp) (doi:10.1088/1751-8113/42/3/035206)

Comment: link: http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~eyuzbash/papers/JPhysA_035206.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It's not true even if $A$ and $B$ have no common nontrivial invariant subspaces.
In dimension $3$, let $A$ be any symmetric matrix with  three distinct nonzero eigenvalues and eigenvectors which have all their entries nonzero, and
$$B = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr} - A$$
Note that $A$ and $A+B$ have no nontrivial invariant subspaces in common, so neither do $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thank you very much for these insightful comments and this counter-example that proves the conjecture wrong. 

However, I believe that a similar property should stand in the particular case I am faced with, which is part of a broader physics question.

Comment: In this case, we are given a diagonal matrix $\boldsymbol{D} \in \mathrm{Diag}_n\left(\mathbb{R}\right) $, that is invertible and has different, unique real values on the diagonal.  We are also provided with a smaller diagonal matrix $\boldsymbol{d} \in \mathrm{Diag}_m\left(\mathbb{R}\right) $, with $m<n$, which is not necessarily invertible and could have repeated values on the diagonal. (continued)

Comment: (end) Finally, we have a rectangular matrix $\boldsymbol{M} \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n,m}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ that is full and random enough that it is of rank $m$ (i.e. $\boldsymbol{M}$ would be invertible where it not for $m \neq n $ ). We want to demonstrate that $\boldsymbol{D} + \boldsymbol{M} \boldsymbol{d} \boldsymbol{D}^\top $ has simple eigenvalues (i.e. no multiplicities higher than 1).